# Android target-version advantages

Tags: android, performance, version

I first wrote an Android app targeted to version 2.2. Later I got an Android 4.1.2 device.

I then upgraded target and minimum to 4.1.2. One advantage is the new runtime exception NetworkOnMainThreadException, which causes the app to crash instead of having a non-responsive GUI. This is an advantages when developing.

However, are there other advantages, besides those at developement time? For instance, can the 4.1.2 device run 4.1.2 app faster than a 2.2 app?

Comment: can you please show us a code snippet where you got this error.

Comment: I'm not looking for a fix to a specific error. Merely I'm trying to find out whether there are other advantages than the one described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage is when you target the newer version of android you will be able to access all the new goodies such as new APIs and services that your app can make use of. Some functionality may be improved to improve performance or to fix bugs.

Regarding will the app run faster as 4.1.2 than 2.2 app, not necessarily, this is completely dependant on the android OS itself and not your app. For example, for 4.3 is now release and has many speed improvements to 4.2. If you target your app to be 4.2 but run it on 4.3, the app will likely run faster due to 4.3 having the speed improvements. If you then targeted your app for 4.3 there would be little difference in performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is also what I would expect...